# Update the count property in the same object while grouping in linq C#

Tags: c#, linq

**Class:**

```
Contact{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        
        public int DocCount { get; set; }

        public string DocName { get; set; }
        

}
```

I have a list of contacts which look like

```
var contactList = new List<Contact>(){ 
                           new Contact(){1,"abc@abc.com","ABC",0,"testdoc1"},
                           new Contact(){1,"abc@abc.com","ABC",0,"testdoc2"},
                           new Contact(){1,"abc@abc.com","ABC",0,"testdoc3"},
                           new Contact(){2,"xyz@abc.com","XYZ",0,"testdoc1"},
                           new Contact(){2,"xyz@abc.com","XYZ",0,"testdoc2"},
                           new Contact(){2,"xyz@abc.com","XYZ",0,"testdoc3"},
                           new Contact(){3,"mop@abc.com","MOP",0,"testdoc1"},
                           new Contact(){3,"mop@abc.com","MOP",0,"testdoc2"},
}
```

I am looking for the output where I need to update the doc count based on the count of the documents uploaded by user.

**output expected is:**

```
{1,"abc@abc.com","ABC",3,"testdoc1 testdoc2 testdoc3"},
{2,"xyz@abc.com","XYZ",3,"testdoc1 testdoc2 testdoc3"},
{3,"mop@abc.com","MOP",2,"testdoc1 testdoc2"}
```

is there is any way to do so,
I know we can introduce new class and do it, but looking for something minimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that updating instances via LINQ is not a good practice - just create a new instance of `Contact`:

```cs
var result = contactList
    .GroupBy(c => c.Id)
    .Select(gr => new Contact
    {
        Id = gr.Key,
        Email = gr.First().Email,
        DisplayName = gr.First().DisplayName,
        DocCount = gr.Count(),
        DocName = string.Join(", ", gr.Select(c => c.DocName))
    })
    .ToList();
```

Or if you expect variance in emails/display names:

```cs
var result = contactList
    .GroupBy(c => (c.Id, c.Email, c.DisplayName))
    .Select(gr => new Contact
    {
        Id = gr.Key.Id,
        Email = gr.Key.Email,
        DisplayName = gr.Key.DisplayName,
        DocCount = gr.Count(),
        DocName = string.Join(", ", gr.Select(c => c.DocName))
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `GroupBy()` and `Select()`:

```
var newList = contactList
        .GroupBy(p => new { p.Id, p.Email, p.DisplayName} )
        .Select(p=> new Contact(p.Key.Id,
                                p.Key.Email,
                                p.Key.DisplayName,
                                p.Count(),
                                string.Join(" ",p.Select(o=>o.DocName))))
        .ToList();
```